# javascript code to display select image is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I've looked other questions and found this code is working but it's not working. I've tried clearing cache in browser but still it's not working. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
     <script>
         function showImage(input) {
          if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#pic').attr('src',e.target.result).width(200).height(200);                     

            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
         }
       }
  </script>
```

HTML code

```
    <input type="file" name="fupload" onchange="showImage(this);"/>
    <img id="pic" src="#" alt="your image" width="200" height="200"/>
```

Comment: The code itself appears to work fine. Please create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and describe what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: You don't need to set the width and hight to 200 again since that is already on your img tag itself

Comment: You should use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead of using the `FileReader`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't include jQuery!

```
<script>
     function showImage(input) {
         if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var preview = document.querySelector('#pic'); //-->Added line;

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                //---Correction is here---
                //$('#pic').attr('src',e.target.result).width(200).height(200);
                preview.src = reader.result;

        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
     }
   }
```

Test it with [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mamun_reza/817tysrh/);